# Does your team's total level affect the amount of Exp gained?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Does your team's level affect the amount of experience gained from a match on multiplayer in Mass Effect 3?

For example, If three people were significantly lower level than the fourth person, would there be any Exp or Credit penalty for anyone?

The reason I ask this is because it is the case in some RPG games. Do not forget ME3 is not only a shooter but an RPG too, and someone mentioned it as a possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you gain XP as absolute values from every action. XP gained is not scaled by level in Mass Effect 3 multiplayer.

You can verify this by getting medals (always the same XP gained) or by killing enemies (the XP gained is based on how much of the enemy's HP you take out before the assist/kill).  If you perform the same action on a level 1 and level 20 character you'll get the same XP.

Also, XP isn't "shared" in any way, except for some medals which give absolute values of XP to everyone. If a level 1 character and a level 20 character get different XP amounts it's because one of the characters performed more actions that gain XP, such as earning more medals or killing more enemies/assists.

Comment: XP _is_ shared in a way. During the challenge, each player earns XP for kills/assists plus XP from individual and squad medals. This is then summed up and **the total XP is given to everyone at the end**. This means that if you have a level 20 character running around killing everything in a Bronze challenge, he will quickly max out his kills medals while the other players will get fewer medals for kills/assists which hurts the total XP received by everyone in the end.